# (C#) O Código não Salva as informações no array (tabela)?

Tags: c#

Eu tenho o código abaixo. O objetivo dele é verificar se já existe na tabela `SalaReservada` um agendamento no mesmo dia/hora/sala. Caso exista, eu verifico a próxima sala que eu trouxe `codSala`, e caso também já exista com essa sala, eu retorno true `erroNaReserva`. Caso só tenha reserva na primeira sala, e na segunda não, posso gravar nessa tabela `SalaReservada`, a reserva.

Erro: Minha tabela `SalaReservada` sempre fica vazia. Quando vou executar a primeira reserva, fala que gravou, mas na segunda, a posição 0 está vazia.

Pergunta: Esse modo de gravar está incorreto?

```
salasReservadas[x] = new SalaReservada { Codigo = codSala[j], DtEntrada = dataIniReuni, DtSaida = dataFimReuni, TempoPerm = tempoReuniao };
```

Código em C#.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ReservaSala
{
    class SalaReservada
    {
        private int codigo;
        private DateTime dtEntrada;
        private DateTime dtSaida;
        private int tempoPerm;

        public int Codigo { get => codigo; set => codigo = value; }
        public DateTime DtEntrada { get => dtEntrada; set => dtEntrada = value; }
        public DateTime DtSaida { get => dtSaida; set => dtSaida = value; }
        public int TempoPerm { get => tempoPerm; set => tempoPerm = value; }

        public SalaReservada[] salasReservadas = new SalaReservada[10];

        public bool VerificaReservaSala(int[] codSala, DateTime dataIniReuni, DateTime dataFimReuni, int tempoReuniao)
        {
            bool[] veriNaReserva = new bool[10];
            bool erroNaReserva = false;
            int horaFinalJaMarcada = 0;
            int horaInicialSerAgendada = 0;
            int j = 0;
            int i = 0;
            int x = 0;

            while (codSala[j] != 0)
            {
                while (salasReservadas[i] != null)
                {
                    if (codSala[j] == salasReservadas[i].codigo
                            && dataIniReuni.ToShortDateString() == salasReservadas[i].dtEntrada.ToShortDateString())
                    {
                        horaFinalJaMarcada = Convert.ToDateTime(salasReservadas[i].dtSaida.ToShortTimeString()).Hour;
                        horaInicialSerAgendada = Convert.ToDateTime(dataIniReuni.ToShortTimeString()).Hour;

                        if (horaInicialSerAgendada <= horaFinalJaMarcada)
                        {
                            veriNaReserva[i] = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    i = i + 1;
                }
                Console.WriteLine(" \n\n\t ******* Reserva ate o momento :" + erroNaReserva);

                j = j + 1;
            }

            for(x = 0; x < i; x++)
            {
                if (veriNaReserva[x])
                { 
                    erroNaReserva = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(!erroNaReserva)
                salasReservadas[x] = new SalaReservada { Codigo = codSala[j], DtEntrada = dataIniReuni, DtSaida = dataFimReuni, TempoPerm = tempoReuniao };

            return erroNaReserva;
        }

    }
}
```

//-----------------------------------------------------

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ReservaSala
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ValidDadosEntrada dadosRecebidos = new ValidDadosEntrada();
            SalasParaReserva verificaReserva = new SalasParaReserva();
            SalaReservada salasReservadas = new SalaReservada();
            int codValidaDadosEntrada = 0;
            string dtIniString = null;
            string dtFimString = null;
            string axSair = null;
            string axInternet = "N";
            string axTv = "N";
            string axWebcam = "N";
            string axLugares = null;
            string axComputador = "N";
            const int V = 12;
            int[] codSala;
            codSala = new int[V];
            bool reservaNok = false;


            do
            {
                dtIniString = null;
                dtFimString = null;
                axSair = null;
                axInternet = "N";
                axTv = "N";
                axWebcam = "N";
                axLugares = null;
                axComputador = "N";

                Console.Title = "Reservas de Sala para Reunião";

                //______________________________________________________________________Valida Data Inicial 
                do
                {
                    codValidaDadosEntrada = 0;
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("\n\n\tVAMOS EFETUAR A RESERVA DA SALA ");
                    Console.Write("\n\tDigite a Data do Inicio Reunião e a Hora (dd/mm/yyyy 00:00:00): ");
                    dtIniString = Console.ReadLine();

                    codValidaDadosEntrada = dadosRecebidos.validaInformacoesEntrada(dtIniString, dtFimString);

                    switch (codValidaDadosEntrada)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            Console.Clear();
                            Console.WriteLine("\n\t ***Favor verificar se a data é Válida e seu Formato!***");
                            Console.ReadLine();
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            Console.Clear();
                            Console.WriteLine("\n\t ***As reuniões devem ser agendadas com no mínimo um dia de antecedência!***");
                            Console.ReadLine();
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            Console.Clear();
                            Console.WriteLine("\n\t ***As reuniões devem ser agendadas com no máximo 40 dia de antecedência!***");
                            Console.ReadLine();
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            Console.Clear();
                            Console.WriteLine("\n\t ***As reuniões devem ser agendadas apenas para os dias úteis!***");
                            Console.ReadLine();
                            break;
                    }
                } while (codValidaDadosEntrada != 0);

                //______________________________________________________________________Valida Data Final
                do
                {
                    codValidaDadosEntrada = 0;
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("\n\n\tVAMOS EFETUAR A RESERVA DA SALA ");
                    Console.WriteLine("\n\tInicio da Reunião: " + dadosRecebidos.DataIni);
                    Console.Write("\n\tDigite a Data do Fim da Reunião e a Hora (dd/mm/yyyy 00:00:00): ");
                    dtFimString = Console.ReadLine();

                    codValidaDadosEntrada = dadosRecebidos.validaInformacoesEntrada(dtIniString, dtFimString);

                    switch (codValidaDadosEntrada)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            Console.Clear();
                            Console.WriteLine("\n\t ***Favor verificar se a data é Válida e seu Formato!***");
                            Console.ReadLine();
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            Console.Clear();
                            Console.WriteLine("\n\t ***A data/hora do Fim da Reunião deve ser maior que a do Inicio!***");
                            Console.ReadLine();
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            Console.Clear();
                            Console.WriteLine("\n\t ***Reuniões não podem durar mais que 8 horas!***");
                            Console.ReadLine();
                            break;
                    }
                } while (codValidaDadosEntrada != 0);

                //______________________________________________________________________Valida informações da sala

                do
                {
                    codValidaDadosEntrada = 0;
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("\n\n\tVAMOS EFETUAR A RESERVA DA SALA ");
                    Console.WriteLine("\n\tInicio da Reunião: " + dadosRecebidos.DataIni);
                    Console.WriteLine("\n\tFim da Reunião: " + dadosRecebidos.DataFim);
                    Console.WriteLine("\n\tTempo de Reunião: " + dadosRecebidos.TempoReuniao);
                    Console.Write("\n\tPRecisa de Quantos Lugares na Sala: ");
                    axLugares = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.Write("\n\tPRecisa de Internet (S/N): ");
                    axInternet = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.Write("\n\tPRecisa de Computador (S/N): ");
                    axComputador = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.Write("\n\tPRecisa de TV (S/N): ");
                    axTv = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.Write("\n\tPRecisa de Webcam (S/N): ");
                    axWebcam = Console.ReadLine();

                    codValidaDadosEntrada = dadosRecebidos.verificaInformacoesSala(axLugares, axInternet, axComputador, axTv, axWebcam);

                    if (codValidaDadosEntrada == 7)
                    {
                        Console.Clear();
                        Console.WriteLine("\n\t ***Você digitou informações inválidas!***");
                        Console.ReadLine();
                    }

                } while (codValidaDadosEntrada != 0);

                codSala = verificaReserva.Reservar(dadosRecebidos.LugaresReserva, dadosRecebidos.InternetReserva, dadosRecebidos.ComputadorReserva, dadosRecebidos.TvReserva, dadosRecebidos.WebcamReserva);

                Console.WriteLine("\n\n Sugestão de Salas ");
                codSala.ToList().ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine(i.ToString()));
                Console.ReadLine();

                if (codSala != null)
                {
                    reservaNok = salasReservadas.VerificaReservaSala(codSala, dadosRecebidos.DataIni, dadosRecebidos.DataFim, dadosRecebidos.TempoReuniao);

                    if (reservaNok)
                        Console.WriteLine("\n\tSua Reserva Não pode ser Feita, pois não há salas Disponíveis Nesse Dia/Hora");
                    else
                        Console.WriteLine("\n\tSua Reserva Foi Realizada Com Sucesso");
                }
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("\n\tSua Reserva Não pode ser Feita, pois não há salas que atendam seus critérios.");



                Console.Write("\n\tPara sair informe 'S', ou para reservar mais 'enter': ");
                axSair = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.ReadKey();

            } while (axSair != "s");
        }//Main
    } //Program
}// ReservaSala
```

//-------------------------------------------

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ReservaSala
{
    class Sala
    {
        private int codigo;
        private int lugares;
        private bool internet;
        private bool computador;
        private bool tv;
        private bool webcam;

        public int Codigo { get => codigo; set => codigo = value; }
        public int Lugares { get => lugares; set => lugares = value; }
        public bool Internet { get => internet; set => internet = value; }
        public bool Tv { get => tv; set => tv = value; }
        public bool Webcam { get => webcam; set => webcam = value; }
        public bool Computador { get => computador; set => computador = value; }
    }
}
```

//------------------------------------------------

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ReservaSala
{
    class ValidDadosEntrada
    {
        private DateTime dataIni;
        private DateTime dataFim;
        private int lugaresReserva;
        private bool internetReserva;
        private bool computadorReserva;
        private bool tvReserva;
        private bool webcamReserva;
        private int tempoReuniao;

        public int LugaresReserva { get => lugaresReserva; set => lugaresReserva = value; }
        public bool InternetReserva { get => internetReserva; set => internetReserva = value; }
        public bool ComputadorReserva { get => computadorReserva; set => computadorReserva = value; }
        public bool TvReserva { get => tvReserva; set => tvReserva = value; }
        public bool WebcamReserva { get => webcamReserva; set => webcamReserva = value; }
        public DateTime DataIni { get => dataIni; set => dataIni = value; }
        public DateTime DataFim { get => dataFim; set => dataFim = value; }
        public int TempoReuniao { get => tempoReuniao; set => tempoReuniao = value; }

        public int validaInformacoesEntrada(string dtIniString, string dtFimString)
        {

            bool dataOk = false;
            bool dadosOk = false;
            int codRetorno = 0;
            string diaSemana = null;
            //Feriados_Nacionais objFeriado = new Feriados_Nacionais();

            if (dtFimString == " " || dtFimString == null)
            {

                dataOk = verificaFormatoData(dtIniString); // Valida formato de Data e Hora
                if (dataOk)
                {
                    this.DataIni = Convert.ToDateTime(dtIniString);
                    dadosOk = verificaDiaAnterior(); // Valida dados Recebidos para Efetuar a reserva

                    if (dadosOk)
                    {
                        dadosOk = verificaDiaApos(); // Valida dados Recebidos para Efetuar a reserva
                        if (dadosOk)
                        {
                            diaSemana = DataIni.DayOfWeek.ToString();
                            if (diaSemana == "Saturday" || diaSemana == "Sunday")
                            {
                                codRetorno = 4;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                            codRetorno = 3;
                    }
                    else
                        codRetorno = 2;
                }
                else
                    codRetorno = 1;
            }
            else //_______________________________________________ Valida data Fim
            {

                dataOk = verificaFormatoData(dtFimString); // Valida formato de Data e Hora
                if (dataOk)
                {
                    this.DataFim = Convert.ToDateTime(dtFimString);
                    dadosOk = verificaDataFim();
                    if (dadosOk)
                    {
                        dadosOk = verificaTempoReuniao();
                        if (!dadosOk)
                            codRetorno = 6;
                    }
                    else
                        codRetorno = 5;
                }
                else
                    codRetorno = 1;
            }
            return codRetorno;
        }


        public bool verificaDiaAnterior()
        {
            DateTime dataAtual = DateTime.Now;
            bool solicitacaoOk = false;
            int result = DateTime.Compare(this.DataIni, dataAtual);

            if (result > 0)
                solicitacaoOk = true;

            return solicitacaoOk;
        }

        public bool verificaDiaApos()
        {
            DateTime dataAtual = DateTime.Now;
            bool solicitacaoOk = false;
            TimeSpan diferenca = this.DataIni.Subtract(dataAtual);
            int diferencaDias = diferenca.Days;

            if (diferencaDias < 40)
                solicitacaoOk = true;

            return solicitacaoOk;
        }

        public bool verificaFormatoData(string dataHora)
        {
            bool dataOk = false;
            DateTime dataValida;
            Regex r = new Regex(@"(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})");
            dataOk = r.Match(dataHora).Success;
            if (dataOk)
            {
                if (!DateTime.TryParse(dataHora, out dataValida))
                    dataOk = false;
            }
            return dataOk;
        }

        public bool verificaDataFim()
        {
            bool tempoOk = false;
            if (this.DataFim > this.DataIni)
                tempoOk = true;

            return tempoOk;
        }

        public bool verificaTempoReuniao()
        {
            bool tempoOk = false;
            TimeSpan tempoOitoHoras = TimeSpan.Parse("08:00:00");
            TimeSpan diferenca = this.DataIni.Subtract(this.DataFim);

            int diferencaDias = diferenca.Hours;
            diferencaDias = Math.Abs(diferencaDias);
            int totalMaximoHoras = tempoOitoHoras.Hours;
            TempoReuniao = diferencaDias;

            if (diferencaDias <= totalMaximoHoras)
                tempoOk = true;

            return tempoOk;
        }

        public int verificaInformacoesSala(string axLugares, string axInternet, string axComputador, string axTv, string axWebcam)
        {
            int codigoRetorno = 0;
            axInternet = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(axInternet);
            axTv = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(axTv);
            axWebcam = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(axWebcam);
            axComputador = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(axComputador);

            try
            {
                lugaresReserva = Convert.ToInt32(axLugares);
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                codigoRetorno = 7;
            }

            if (codigoRetorno == 0)
            {
                switch (axInternet)
                {
                    case "N":
                        internetReserva = false;
                        break;
                    case "S":
                        internetReserva = true;
                        break;
                    default:
                        codigoRetorno = 7;
                        break;
                }
            }

            if (codigoRetorno == 0)
            {
                switch (axComputador)
                {
                    case "N":
                        ComputadorReserva = false;
                        break;
                    case "S":
                        ComputadorReserva = true;
                        break;
                    default:
                        codigoRetorno = 7;
                        break;
                }
            }

            if (codigoRetorno == 0)
            {
                switch (axTv)
                {
                    case "N":
                        tvReserva = false;
                        break;
                    case "S":
                        tvReserva = true;
                        break;
                    default:
                        codigoRetorno = 7;
                        break;
                }
            }

            if (codigoRetorno == 0)
            {
                switch (axWebcam)
                {
                    case "N":
                        webcamReserva = false;
                        break;
                    case "S":
                        webcamReserva = true;
                        break;
                    default:
                        codigoRetorno = 7;
                        break;
                }
            }

            return codigoRetorno;
        }
    }
}
```

// ---------------------------------------------

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ReservaSala
{
    class SalasParaReserva
    {
        public List<Sala> salas = new List<Sala>();

        public SalasParaReserva()
        {
            salas[0] = new Sala { Codigo = 1, Lugares = 10, Internet = true, Computador = true, Tv = true, Webcam = true };
            salas[1] = new Sala { Codigo = 2, Lugares = 10, Internet = true, Computador = true, Tv = true, Webcam = true };
            salas[2] = new Sala { Codigo = 3, Lugares = 10, Internet = true, Computador = true, Tv = true, Webcam = true };
            salas[3] = new Sala { Codigo = 4, Lugares = 10, Internet = true, Computador = true, Tv = true, Webcam = true };
            salas[4] = new Sala { Codigo = 5, Lugares = 10, Internet = true, Computador = true, Tv = true, Webcam = true };
            salas[5] = new Sala { Codigo = 6, Lugares = 10, Internet = true, Computador = false, Tv = false, Webcam = false };
            salas[6] = new Sala { Codigo = 7, Lugares = 10, Internet = true, Computador = false, Tv = false, Webcam = false };
            salas[7] = new Sala { Codigo = 8, Lugares = 3, Internet = true, Computador = true, Tv = true, Webcam = true };
            salas[8] = new Sala { Codigo = 9, Lugares = 3, Internet = true, Computador = true, Tv = true, Webcam = true };
            salas[9] = new Sala { Codigo = 10, Lugares = 3, Internet = true, Computador = true, Tv = true, Webcam = true };
            salas[10] = new Sala { Codigo = 11, Lugares = 20, Internet = false, Computador = false, Tv = false, Webcam = false };
            salas[11] = new Sala { Codigo = 12, Lugares = 20, Internet = false, Computador = false, Tv = false, Webcam = false };
        }

        public int[] Reservar(int axlugares, bool axInternet, bool axComputador, bool axTv, bool axWebcam)
        {
            int[] axCodigo = new int[12];
            int x = 0;
            bool axControle = false;
            bool axControleI = false;
            bool axControleC = false;
            bool axControleT = false;
            bool axControleW = false;

            for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
            {
                axControle = false;
                axControleI = false;
                axControleC = false;
                axControleT = false;
                axControleW = false;

                if (!axInternet && !axComputador && !axTv && !axWebcam)
                    axControle = true;

                if (salas[i].Internet && axInternet)
                    axControleI = true;

                if (salas[i].Computador && axComputador)
                    axControleC = true;

                if (salas[i].Tv && axTv)
                    axControleT = true;

                if (salas[i].Webcam && axWebcam)
                    axControleW = true;

                if (axControle || axControleI && axControleC && axControleT && axControleW) { 
                    if (salas[i].Lugares >= axlugares)
                    {
                        axCodigo[x] = salas[i].Codigo;
                        x = x + 1;
                    }
                }

            }
            return axCodigo;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cadê a parte do código que faz a reserva? Pergunto pois pode ser nele que se encontra o erro.

Comment: if(!erroNaReserva)
                salasReservadas[x] = new SalaReservada { Codigo = codSala[j], DtEntrada = dataIniReuni, DtSaida = dataFimReuni, TempoPerm = tempoReuniao }; // Será feito nesse trecho do código, somente após a verificação se já existe a reserva ou não.

Comment: Você nao está salvando na tabela só de instanciar um novo objeto nesse código do new SalaReservada, vc tem que pegar esse novo objeto criado e inserir no seu contexto e salvar o mesmo

Comment: @RebecaNonato Esse `if(!erroNaReserva) salasReservadas[x] = ...` é o código de verificação se a reserva. Eu quero o código que preenche as reservas.

Comment: @AugustoVasques coloquei na pergunta, o código que recebo as informações do usuário, e chamo para verificar se a reserva pode ou não ser realizada.

Comment: @JoãoPauloAmorim O "salvar" é somente guardar as informações na tabela. Pois nesse código eu não uso BD, somente é online, o usuário durante a mesma execução, irá chamar o reserva quantas vezes quiser. E assim que ele chama, eu teria que "guardar" as informações em uma tabela online.

Comment: Entendi, o código está bem extenso com esse tanto de arrays, você nao pode transformar isso em listas? assim fica bem mais legivel, mais facil a verificação e mais facil de vc popular também esses caras.

Comment: Essas duas linhas
`ValidDadosEntrada dadosRecebidos = new ValidDadosEntrada();`
`SalasParaReserva verificaReserva = new SalasParaReserva();`
possuem referencia as classes `ValidDadosEntrada` e `SalasParaReserva`sem essas classes não consigo executar seu código.

Comment: @AugustoVasques Incluí todo o código (classes) do programa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que a instância `salas` é do tipo `List<Sala>` e estava sendo populada como se fosse uma instância do vetor`Sala[]`.

**Existem duas soluções para esse problema.**

A primeira solução consiste em modificar o tipo `salas` de uma instância de `List<Sala>` para uma instancia de vetor`Sala[]`:

```
//É só alterar a classe de salas de List<Sala> para Sala[] 
public Sala[] salas = new Sala[12];
```

A segunda solução, um pouco mais trabalhosa, é popular o `List<Sala>` usando o método [`List<T>.Add(T)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.add?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
 public List<Sala> salas = new List<Sala>();

        public SalasParaReserva()
        {
            salas.Add(new Sala { Codigo = 1, Lugares = 10, Internet = true, Computador = true, Tv = true, Webcam = true });
            salas.Add(new Sala { Codigo = 2, Lugares = 10, Internet = true, Computador = true, Tv = true, Webcam = true });
            salas.Add(new Sala { Codigo = 3, Lugares = 10, Internet = true, Computador = true, Tv = true, Webcam = true });
            salas.Add(new Sala { Codigo = 4, Lugares = 10, Internet = true, Computador = true, Tv = true, Webcam = true });
            salas.Add(new Sala { Codigo = 5, Lugares = 10, Internet = true, Computador = true, Tv = true, Webcam = true });
            salas.Add(new Sala { Codigo = 6, Lugares = 10, Internet = true, Computador = false, Tv = false, Webcam = false });
            salas.Add(new Sala { Codigo = 7, Lugares = 10, Internet = true, Computador = false, Tv = false, Webcam = false });
            salas.Add(new Sala { Codigo = 8, Lugares = 3, Internet = true, Computador = true, Tv = true, Webcam = true });
            salas.Add(new Sala { Codigo = 9, Lugares = 3, Internet = true, Computador = true, Tv = true, Webcam = true });
            salas.Add(new Sala { Codigo = 10, Lugares = 3, Internet = true, Computador = true, Tv = true, Webcam = true });
            salas.Add(new Sala { Codigo = 11, Lugares = 20, Internet = false, Computador = false, Tv = false, Webcam = false });
            salas.Add(new Sala { Codigo = 12, Lugares = 20, Internet = false, Computador = false, Tv = false, Webcam = false });
        }
```